# Ridiculous Error on Unity 5.6.4p4 Method Name doesn't exists

Tags: unity, c#

I am facing a strange issue on Unity version 5.6.4p4 
The code compiles and runs just perfectly fine in editor but when I build it for android I see an error message saying that my method doesn't exists. I have checked many times but there is no such issue. I am not doing anything wrong. Can anyone suggest what could be wrong ?

[image]

Comment: Have you any [preprocessor directives](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html) in your code somewhere?

Comment: holy moly!
I was going all crazy.
I wasn't able to discover. I tried everything. Only after your comment I came to know that I have generated the method through Visual Studio and it has placed the method in the UnityEditor section of my class. 
That was causing issue !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @Hellium 
The issue was that I generated my method through Visual studio tool which placed my method in editor only region of my class. That's why it wasn't compiling when I built for android. 
Lesson Learnt: Don't rely on auto code generation always :D They put your code anywhere ! Even in places that aren't always correct.